# Java: Whats the best way to implement an observer pattern which redirects different instances to different subscriber?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

i have a class Record with different sub classes (RecordA, RecordB, and so on).
And i have a class which receives some Objects and creates those differet Records.
And i want something like an observer pattern, but the oberservers are only interessted in some Subtypes.

So e.g. i have an observer who wants to receive all instances of RecordA and RecordC.
And another observer wants to receive all instances of RecordB.

Whats the best way to do something like this?

Comment: May be overkill for just 2 types of observables and observers, but as soon as you have more than two, an event-based system may be better. Every "observable" can then emit multiple (types of) events, and every "observer" can register for the events they want to track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two basic approaches:

- **Filtering in the observer**: each observer gets notified on all records. The observer then filters out the records of interest and discards the other notifications. This is an easy and simple approach when the notifications are local (inter-process communication).
- **Filtering in the observable**: each observer defines on registration, which notifications (record types) he wants to receive. The observable will then filter and notify the observer only if the record matches the subscription. This is a bit more complex and requires book-keeping of the subscription options, but pays out for non-local (intra-process) communication.

Code example:

An `Observer` for a message of generic type `M`:

```
public interface Observer<M> {
    void notify(M message);
}
```

An `Observable` which supports both variants: filtering in the observable, and no filtering (can then be done in the Observer):

```
public interface Observable<M> {

    void subscribe(Observer<M> observer, Predicate<M> filter);

    default void subscribe(Observer<M> observer) {
        subscribe(observer, message -> true);
    }
}
```

A simple generic default implementation:

```
public class SimpleObservable<M> implements Observable<M> {

    private Map<Observer<M>, Predicate<M>> subscriptions = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void subscribe(Observer<M> observer, Predicate<M> filter) {
        subscriptions.put(observer, filter);
    }

    public void notifyObservers(M message) {
        subscriptions.forEach((observer, filter) -> {
            if (filter.test(message)) observer.notify(message);
        });
    }
}
```

Everything in action: an observable for date/time messages (implementations of `Temporal`), and four different observers which are interested in different date/time classes, where two of them filter ob the subscription, one does its own filtering, and one just consumes all the events:

```
Observer<Temporal> timeObserver = message -> System.out.println("The time is: " + message);
Observer<Temporal> dateObserver = message -> System.out.println("The date is: " + message);
Observer<Temporal> dateTimeObserver = message -> {
    if (message instanceof LocalDateTime) {
        System.out.println("The date/time is: " + message);
    }
};
Observer<Temporal> generalObserver = message -> System.out.println("Now is: " + message);

SimpleObservable<Temporal> clock = new SimpleObservable<>();
clock.subscribe(timeObserver, temporal -> temporal instanceof LocalTime);
clock.subscribe(dateObserver, temporal -> temporal.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("LocalDate"));
clock.subscribe(dateTimeObserver); // does its own filtering
clock.subscribe(generalObserver); // no filtering

clock.notifyObservers(LocalDate.now());
clock.notifyObservers(LocalTime.now());
clock.notifyObservers(LocalDateTime.now());
clock.notifyObservers(OffsetDateTime.now());
```

Output:

```
Now is: 2021-07-13
The date is: 2021-07-13
The time is: 11:37:05.997223
Now is: 11:37:05.997223
Now is: 2021-07-13T11:37:05.997319
The date/time is: 2021-07-13T11:37:05.997319
Now is: 2021-07-13T11:37:05.997626+02:00
```